# Garage Conversion to home office in Los Angeles, plan advice and insulation question

Tags: garage, attic-conversion, advice

I'm not handy, though I am a software engineer by trade so I like to solve problems and build things, just haven't had much experience doing that in the physical world much. I'd like to take this project on for the education, confidence, and experience.

Here is what I am starting with:

1. A 17'x20' garage built in the 90's
2. A cheap garage door
3. An old window and an old door
4. Concrete slab foundation
5. Exposed wall framing (except for some areas with drywall, but no insulation)
6. An unvented roof (see pictures)

Here is what I would like to end up with:

1. Enough insulation to keep the space climate controller year round.
2. Outlets in walls and a couple of outlets in ceiling.
3. I'd like to keep the ceiling exposed, so I can get the extra height, and I can keep the joists (I think that's what the horizontal pieces are called?) exposed, so I can hang/clip things onto them which would be helpful for using the space as a video recording studio.

I've included an example of what I would like to go for in terms of the roof and the aesthetics, and I've also included photos of my existing roof: https://imgur.com/a/f7zm8vc

Here's what I plan on doing:

1. Insulate and drywall the walls (after running wires for plugs)
2. Replace the garage door with a double-paned window door
3. Insulate the ceiling (seems like closed cell foam would work? I was hoping to insulate + drywall the ceiling like the walls, but it seems that's dangerous because of moisture, which I was curious about as Los Angeles is pretty dry)
4. Install an AC (thinking a mini split?)
5. Paint

I'm feeling confident about the walls, paint, electrical, and walls. I would get professional help with the windows/doors, but I'm unsure about the ceiling.

Am I crazy for wanting to do this without experience? Is it crazy to do so little to a garage and expect it to be comfortable? Is there a cheap DIY version of ceiling insulation to keep it comfortable?

If I can just paint the ceiling and get a big enough mini split to compensate, is that a feasible option?

Comment: So you're thinking to insulate below the roof decking, and then drywall the bottom of the rafters?  Or leave the insulation exposed?

Comment: You don't want to go cheap on the roof and make up for it with a larger AC unit.  LA electric rates are through the roof (no pun intended) and a home office would run the AC unit a lot.